# Deleting terms from the Wordpress wp terms table

Tags: wp-query, wp-insert-post, terms

what wp function do i use so that I can delete a term without worrying about the related tables such as wp term relationships and wp term taxonomy?

Also if a post has a relationship to the deleted term and it's the only relationship to any term does wp take care of the necessary and  it's associated back to uncategorized ? What if there is no uncategorized term neither?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this: [`wp_delete_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_term)

Edit:
Did a little dig around. With custom taxonomies, if you delete the term, the posts will not be assigned a new one. With 'category', whichever you set as the default from 'Writing Settings' will be assigned to the post. Besides, if you want to set the default category from code, use `update_option('default_category', '<category name>')`. There's a third argument with `wp_delete_term`, using which you can force a default category, but I really couldn't find how to use this argument.
(Ref: ../wp-includes/taxonomy.php, l. no. 1681)

Comment: Also if a post has a relationship to the deleted term and it's the only relationship to any term does wp take care of the necessary and it's associated back to uncategorized ? What if there is no uncategorized term neither?

Comment: I guess I'll have to look at it with an example!

Comment: Yes please. This answer has a quality score of 56. You can do better. Always, always add a code example. :)

Comment: Thanks! Have edited my answer a bit... couldn't get an example though!